# How to router jump in redux saga when login success?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-saga

thanks for check this question. I am new come to react. I use the react hooks and redux-saga.I want router jump to `/home` when login successed. I used the `connected-react-router` and `history` to do that, Is this a common method to do this? Please tell me if there is a better way. now when i login success. the page doesn't jump to '/home'. this is my code.

`reducer.ts`

```js
const initialUser = (): UserState => {
  const token = TokenStorage.getToken();
  if (token === null) {
    return { isAuthenticated: false };
  }
  return UserModel.getUser(token);
};

function user(state = initialUser(), action: UserAction): UserState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    case LOGIN_FAILED:
      TokenStorage.clear();
      return { isAuthenticated: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const createRootReducer = (history: History) =>
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    user,
  });

// when add router into combineReducers. the RootState is wrong.. how to fix?
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof createRootReducer>;
```

store/index.ts

```js
export default function configureStore(history: History) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const composeEnhancers =
    (typeof window === 'object' &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
    compose;

  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)))
  );

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
  return store;
}
```

saga.ts

```js
function* LoginRequestSaga(username: string, password: string) {
  try {
    const result: ILoginResponseData = yield call(
      fetchLogin,
      username,
      password
    );
    if (result.code === '1') {
      TokenStorage.storeToken(result.token);
      message.success(result.msg);
      const user = UserModel.getUser(result.token);
      yield put(loginSuccess(user));
      yield put(push('/home'));    <----- this line doesn't run....
    } else {
      message.error(result.msg);
      yield put(loginFailed());
    }
  } catch (err) {
    message.error(err);
    yield put(loginFailed());
  }
}
```

index.ts

```js
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
export const store = configureStore(history);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Router />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

my router

```js
const renderRoutes = routes.map(({ path, exact, component, key }) => (
  <Route exact={exact || false} path={path} key={key} component={component} />
));

const Routers: React.FC = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
      <Switch>{renderRoutes}</Switch>
    </Suspense>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

If you want check the more detail you can check this [repo](https://github.com/glepnir/go-react-jwt)
Thanks all.

Comment: I update the repo

Answer (score 0):

Well , I have a very similar project, same method to login (with redux-saga). In order to achieve the redirection I used this method in my `Login.js` component:

```
const history = useHistory()
const { isLogged, state } = useSelector(state => ({
    isLogged: state.logged.isLogged,
    state: state.login,
}))

if(isLogged) {
    history.push(routes.dashboard)
}
```

Basically I store the `isLogged` into a reducer , and check it in the `Login.js` component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, At the beginning, I did the same, but I think the best logic is to handle login in saga to jump, instead of judging the state in the store in login to jump, what do you think?

Comment: Well, i considered the case where the user just uses the /login link when it's logged, the saga wont't trigger, and it will ask to login again. So why do that ? If the user is logged i check on the Login page, and redirect him. Also you can use ```<Redirect to="/newRoute" />``` from ```react-router-dom``` , not only the history.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service history containing the createBrowserHistory (), and use it throughout your application

history.js:

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory ();

export default history;
```

Where do you want to use:

```
import history from '~ / services / history';

history.push ('/ dashboard');
```

Comment: I tried this. but doesn't work. Does history need to be passed to saga?

Comment: when i use history.push in saga the url changed to `/home`,but the page doesn't render Home component..

Comment: In order to make it work this way, you need to provide the same ```history``` to ```BrowserRouter``` : ```<BrowserRouter history={history}> //...rest of code``` and the history must be the same one from ```/services/history```.